# How to format by comparing values in another sheet using conditional formatting in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets with exact same structure. I want compare the values (check if values in sheet1 is greater than values in sheet 2) and highlight them as red. I am a complete beginner when it comes to equations in excel.

Would appreciate it if someone can help me out. I am using Excel 2013 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following worksheets:

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]

To highlight cells in the `Sheet2` that are less-than-or-equal-to the corresponding cells in `Sheet1`, select `A1:A5` in `Sheet2` and use the following conditional formatting code:

[image: Formatting Rule]

**Result:**

[image: Result]